# MFCPropertySheet - How do I increase Tree Control's Width?

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm using the `MFCPropertySheet` class with `PropSheetLook` set to `PropSheetLook_Tree`.
The problem I'm having is that the tree control is small, and I can't find a way to increase it's width.

I looked at the documentation, and the only mildly related function I can find is `GetNavBarWidth`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You can change the nav control width by passing a second argument to 
`CMFCPropertySheet::SetLook`.